# Does ClickHouse support map fields?

Tags: clickhouse

I want to have a field that map from a string to a nested type:

```
CREATE TABLE table
(
    // Other fields ...

    MapColumn  Map<String, StructType>
)
```

For example, I need to do the following filter efficiently:

```
WHERE MapColumn['key'].PropertyInt32 > 5
```

What is the best way to do this in ClickHouse?

Comment: look at [nested data structure](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nested-data-structures/nested/). Your table should be redesigned (split into several ones) to follow your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Map(key, value) data type stores key:value pairs.

Parameters

- key — The key part of the pair. String or Integer.
- value — The value part of the pair. String, Integer or Array.

> Warning
>
> Currently Map data type is an experimental feature. To work with it
> you must set allow_experimental_map_type = 1.

To get the value from an a Map('key', 'value') column, use a['key'] syntax. This lookup works now with a linear complexity.

Examples

Consider the table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_map (a Map(String, UInt64)) ENGINE=Memory;
INSERT INTO table_map VALUES ({'key1':1, 'key2':10}), ({'key1':2,'key2':20}), ({'key1':3,'key2':30});
```

Select all key2 values:

```
SELECT a['key2'] FROM table_map;
```

Result:

```
┌─arrayElement(a, 'key2')─┐
│                      10 │
│                      20 │
│                      30 │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

reference link: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/map/